# python reading csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have just some informational questions regarding python and its syntax. I have a csv file with 5000 rows and I am reading it and printing it to the screen like this

```
for i in range(5):
    print csv_file.readline(),
```

1. What does that trailing comma do? I mean I can see what it does to the output, but what I want to know is why it does it.
2. Each time this code is run it reads the next increment of five rows. I find that curious as I would have thought it would always read the same five rows. So python is somehow keeping track of where it is in the file?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
for i in range(3):
    print i
print "---"
for i in range(5):
    print i,
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
---
0 1 2 3 4
```

1. The normal behavior for the "print" keyword is that it adds the newline character "\n" after what is printed so that the next printed statement is on a new line. However, your csv file also has "\n" at the end of each line. So you initially have "\n\n". The comma indicates that a newline character should not be added to a printed statement and so you only have the newline character from the csv file.
2. The file handle (handle=open('myFile')) keeps track of the file position as long as the thread is executing and the file handle is not closed. Once you use "csv_file.close()" and reopen the file, it will start from the beginning of the file. If the script completes execution and closes, it will also close all open file handles and subsequent execution will start from the beginning of the file. The only time I can think this would not be the case is if you are getting "csv_file" from a different thread that continues running.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear explanation.